# python .lower doesnt work without the (), im curious why

Tags: python

So I came across this but don't fully understand why this is the case:

```
    count = 0
    Got_one = 0
    while(count<1):
        print('\n')
        response = input("Did you get one?\n:").lower()#<--This part here
        if response == 'yes':
            Got_one += 1
            #...ect
```

At one point of the script I had typed up **.lower** without the **()**. The code ran fine but the script failed to +1 when I inputted "yes", instead it printed out a value of 0, most likely due to the "Got_one" variable being set to 0 in the very beginning. However, as soon as I typed up the **()** the code worked as intended and +1 to the value after inputting "yes".

So, why is this the case? Is .lower on its own lowering everything after it or just something I don't understand about Python yet?

Comment: Your one problem has nothing to do with the other one, try to read about `str.lower()` method.

Comment: Everything in python is first class objects, which means you can create, destroy, pass to a function, return as a value, and have all the rights as other variables in the programming language have. Since `lower` is a function(Which is a first class object) you can assign to a variable like `response = input("Did you get one?\n:").lower`,  And Invoke later by `response()`

Answer (score 2):

`.lower()` is a built-in method for the String object in Python. The reason you need the parenthesis is to execute the function on the string.

Without the parenthesis, you are simply accessing the String.lower attribute, which is a function pointer. Therefore, without the parenthesis, you are setting `response = String.lower`, which will not pass the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

the difference is that calling it with no parenthesis is your just calling the method but not the value of that method and calling it with parenthesis your calling the value of that method

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is because `.lower()` is a class method, not a class attribute (which would be written as `.lower`).
Therefore, you have to use parenthesis to indicate that you are trying to call a method.
Since it does not take any arguments, you simply only put empty parenthesis behind it.

A class method is a function that belongs to a class object, in this case a `str` object.
A class attribute is a variable that belongs to this object.

Comment: Methods are attributes that happen to be functions

Answer (score 0):

To add to 1313e's answer, .lower() is actually a built-in *method* (functions for object classes) that you're performing on the string *object* (because everything in Python is an object), which is why you call `'this string'.lower()` and not, say, `lower('this string')`

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are merely making a reference to the `lower` class method (function) of the class object `str`. For reference:

```
foo = "ALL CAPS"
bar = foo.lower
bar
>>> <built-in method lower of str object at 0x1038e1570>
bar()
>>> 'all caps'
```